# USB miner and risk of fire

Tags: safety

I wanted to try-out mining from a pool from a raspberry pi. I ended up buying a USB ASIC miner (not sure I can post brand here). It's a bit bigger than a USB drive and mounted with heat sinks and fan. It is connected to a USB hub which is powered separately. I think it draws about 10 watts ( 5v x 2A)
My question is, if I let it turned on all the time, does it have a risk of fire? The electricity in my house is reliable (wires are safe), but I'm concerned about the heat. Or any other risk it starts a fire while I'm sleeping (for now I'm not letting it on when I leave the house).
Am I being paranoid? Any particular recommendation?

Comment: *"Any particular recommendation?"* - leave it turned off, the Bitcoin mining outcome will be unaffected and there will be almost no risks of fire. Note: 10W isn't a serious  fire risk. People used to happily install and use 100W light bulbs.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick that's actually what I did a few days ago. I was mining DOGE btw. It only took a few minutes calculation that with the hashrate I got, I would need to mine 20 per month. I was just at 1 after 5 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is wondering the same, mining from a small 10W USB ASIC miner is not really a fire hazard if you take proper precautions:

- let air flow around the device
- don't place it near easily flammable material

But as I have experienced, I was on average 5 MH/s which is not going to get me very far.